# Rails & wysihtml5 - saving when changed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, wysihtml5

we are using the gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', '0.3.1.13'.  I would like to save the changed content from the textarea when the focus is lost.

I have tried to use jquery directly in the view, surrounded by script-tags:

```
$("textarea").live("blur", function(){ alert("Focus lost"); });
```

If I use "blur" (or focusout) the alert is triggered several times at page loading but not when loosing focus, when I use 'change' nothing happens at all.

In another attempt I tried to hook into the wysihtml5-event with the same behavior:

```
function integrate_wysihtml5() {
var editor = $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).wysihtml5({
        "font-styles": false, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
        "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
        "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
        "html": false, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
        "link": false, //Button to insert a link. Default true
        "image": false, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
        "color": false //Button to change color of font  
    });
});

function onChange() { alert("The content of the editor has changed"); };
editor.on("change", onChange);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.textarea').wysihtml5({
    events: {
        change: function() {
            var html = this.textarea.getValue();
            //ajax method
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the good way to catch change event :

```
editor.composer.element.addEventListener("keyup", myOnChange);
editor.on("aftercommand:composer", myOnChange);
```

but i do not think your each is good, wysihtml5 is not made to work on multiple editable part, here you use the bootstrap edition but i think it's the same.
that's mainly why i write [jquery.scribe](https://github.com/r043v/jQuery.scribe)

so, maybe like that ?

```
$('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
    var editor = $(elem).wysihtml5({
        "font-styles": false, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
        "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
        "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
        "html": false, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
        "link": false, //Button to insert a link. Default true
        "image": false, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
        "color": false //Button to change color of font  
    });

    editor.composer.element.addEventListener("keyup", myOnChange);
    editor.on("aftercommand:composer", myOnChange);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm attaching the listener like this:

```
$("#msgtextarea").data("wysihtml5").editor.on("change",function(){
   // Do your stuff
})
```

Hope It helps.